# A function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $A $ is a subspace of $X$ such that $f|A$ is continuous but $f$ is not continuous at any point of $A$.

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I am not able to find any example.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't $\;f|A\;$ the restriction of $\;f\;$ to $\;A\;$ ? Because if it is then I don't quite understand the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $X=\Bbb R$, $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\in\Bbb Q\\0&x\notin\Bbb Q\end{cases}$ and $A=\Bbb Q$.

Comment: This has the added advantage that $f$ is nowhere continuous at all of $\mathbb{R}$, not just $A$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f$ be any function at all, and let $A=\varnothing$.

Comment: $f|\emptyset$ is continuous at _every_ point of $\emptyset$

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Yes, and it is also not continuous at every point!

Comment: You're +1 right

Answer (score 3):

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = 1$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$. Moreover, set $A = \{0\}$, then $f \vert A : \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ is obviously continuous, but $f$ is not continuous at every point of $A$.